# Finding tangent angle

Tags: conic-sections

Finding the tangent angle between the negative $x$-axis and the parabola $$y=-ax^2+bx$$($a,b>0$) at $(x_0,y_0)$ :
I am trying to find the tangent angle with negative $x $ axis for a parabolic curve. I assume the equation of tangent line will be
$$y=mx+C$$ and the equation for the parabola $$y=-a{x^2}+bx$$
  So,$$-a{x^2}+bx-mx-C=0$$
Again  $${y_0}=m{x_0}+C$$
We obtain 
$$a{x^2}+(m-b)x+{y_0}-m{x_0}=0$$
So if this tangent line is to be the desired tangent, then this $x$ has to be unique. That is,
$$(m-b)^2-4(y_0-mx_0)a=0$$
Then $m$ has two values. So it seems to me complicated what $m$ I have to choose.Now what can I do?

Comment: Derivatives will help you

Comment: Can i say $\frac{dy}{dx}=\tan(π-\theta)$?

Comment: What you are doing its just getting the intersection point between a general parabola and a general line, you are not using the condition that the line has to be tangent to the parabola

Comment: I am just interested to the angle of tangent, at a given point of parabola, with the negative x axis.

Comment: I suppose you are looking for the complementary angle so yes $\frac{dy}{dx} = \tan{(\pi - \theta)}$ is correct

Answer (score 1):

If you  take into account that $(x_0,y_0)$ is on the parabola, the  last equation in $m$ can be rewritten in the following way:
\begin{align}
(m-b)^2-4&\bigl(-ax_0^2+(b-m)x_0\bigr)a=m^2-2mb+b^2+4a^2x_0^2-4abx_0+4ax_0m \\
&=m^2+2(2ax_0-b)m+\underbrace{b^2+4a^2x_0^2-4abx_0}_{\textstyle(2ax_0-b)^2}\\[-1ex]
&=\bigl(m+(2ax_0-b)\bigr)^2,
\end{align}
so that the last equation has a *double root* (in $m$), and you don't have to choose.